# UIPickerView for Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am creating a **unit convertor** app using a pickerview with three components and a plist..first one is category component and second and third are unit components. What i need is when i click an item in category component the remaining two components should get the units regarding that particular category. Can some one help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

this is for selecting the same row in each component

here i did with first component do like that for ur logic

so change this method and u have to implement UIPickerViewDelegate

```
 - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

            if (component == 1) {

                [pickerView selectRow:row inComponent:1 animated:YES];

                [pickerView selectRow:row inComponent:2 animated:YES];


            }


        }
```